# Failed to start monitoring changes to 'C:\********\global.asax'

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, error-handling, global-asax

Please help me to solve this error.

Till this morning my application was working fine then suddenly this error has come up.

I even took the backup from the development server but it's throwing this error.

Comment: Take a loot at this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104456/failed-to-start-monitoring-changes-to-path-global-asax and here http://amitabhk.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/failed-to-start-monitoring-changes-to-path-global-asax/

Comment: My initial reaction would be some sort of permissions change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the links... this doesn't solve the problem, but lets you get around it.

Run Visual Studio as the Administrator user in order to get around this problem.

If anyone can figure out which folders/permission need to be adjusted, please post! (I've gone through the suggestions on the links and a bunch other steps without any success..)

Answer (score 1):

If *"Run Visual Studio as the Administrator"* and *"Change User Access Control" to "Notify me when programs tries to make changes to my computer"* doesn't work (as stated in previous answers), look for impersonations in *web.config*, especially if you running a web service app.

And for testing/running simply **comment out**:

`<identity impersonate="true" userName="XXX\XXX" password="XXX" />`

Or **grant permissions** to impersonated identity user to:

```
 C:\Users\[your_user_id]\AppData\Local\Temp
```

and 
`C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\...\Temporary ASP.NET`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add additional info for the previous answer (which solved the problem in our case). In addition, you need to run VS 2005 as Admin. Sometimes, you will not get the UAC Prompt, so in this case, goto Control Panel, Action Center, Change User Access Control, and set it to "Notify me when programs tries to make changes to my computer" (2nd choice from the bottom).

It took us 5 days to find out why the errors are not cleared from VS 2005 under Windows 7 64 bit. But now, it is OK.